# WXU 3.0.5 not found with the latest version of wxgtk 3.0

Tags: linux, manjaro, software-packaging, pacman-package-manager

So I'm packaging darkradiant as a [pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman) package. But when I execute [darkradiant](https://bin.privacytools.io/?87c85d6fdf0bc4f1#AeSXyVavvJk8W4ow2drzJG1UXJgWLO9er0WPeANnL18=) on the terminal it complains:

> darkradiant: /usr/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.0.so.0: version `WXU_3.0.5'
>   not found (required by darkradiant)
>
> darkradiant: /usr/lib/libwx_gtk3u_core-3.0.so.0: version `WXU_3.0.5'
>   not found (required by
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/darkradiant/libwxutil-2.7.0.so)

The thing is that's the latest [announced](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) 3.0 version of [wxgtk](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/wxgtk). If you install [3.1](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=wxgtk-dev) then darkradiant complains it cannot find 3.0 at all.

Any idea why this could be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Root [cause](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/18739#ticket) was: wxgtk also tags incomplete releases, leading to mistakes to third party developers.